# Does all AMFPHP 2.1 requests starts a new session?

Tags: php, amfphp

I was trying to minimize the db hits by storing data in session when the session starts and then return the data from the session for the subsequent requests. But It looks like it is not working as I expected

See test remote method below

**update:** added session_start() which I missed to copy

Main.php - Service class

```
class Main{
      public function amfRequest(){
         session_start();
         $test = new Test();
         return $test->testSession();
      }
  }
```

Test.php

```
class Test(){
     public function testSession(){
     if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])){
        return "setting sesion variable";
        $_SESSION['test'] = "all set!";
    }else{
        return "getting session variable";
           }                
      }

}
```

Expected result

- 1st run - return **setting sesion variable**
- subsequent runs - return **getting session variable**

But it is always returns **setting sesion variable**

Does AMF PHP destroys the session every time I request? if so, how to handle sessions then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is NO. The results I was getting because the session was destroyed somewhere else in the code, thus I was always getting isset($_SESSION['test']) as false.

Answer (score -1):

Basic codding info. Workflow breaks in return. so `$_SESSION['test'] = "all set!";` newer gets call.